# Split a list into sub lists of decreasing size

Tags: python, list, sublist

Suppose I have a list as

```
list = [0,1,2,3]
```

How would I split the lists into something like

```
new_list = [[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```

I've tried using:

```
def change(list):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        total += [list:]
    return new_list
```

but I get a return value of

```
 new_list = [0,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3]
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, 
thanks.

Comment: `total += [list:]` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension, which iterates over the length of original list. Also, I have used variable name `lst`, since `list` is a python type.

Here you go:

```
>>> lst = [0,1,2,3]
>>> [lst[i:] for i in range(len(lst))]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I finally finished my project after just being stuck on that bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist=[]
list = [0,1,2,3]
i=0
while i<len(list):
    newlist.append(list[i:])
    i=i+1

print newlist
```

Comment: A `for` loop is much more Pythonic than this `while`. And a list comprehension more Pythonic than `for`+`append`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map` with `lambda`

```
 In [14]: map(lambda x: list[x:], xrange(len(list)))
 Out[14]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: That only seems to work because `list` is `[0,1,2,3]`. It wouldn't work with other lists.

Comment: Now it's correct, but it's basically identical to mu's answer except using the less Pythonic map+lambda instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: @interjay yes its not preferred over `list comprehension`, but i am just trying to give answer in another way, and it's not wrong i think.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
from itertools import islice

# Input list 
List1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

# [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],[10],[11]
length_to_split = [4, 3, 2, 1, 1]

# Using islice
X = iter(List1)
sublists = [list(islice(X, elem)) for elem in length_to_split]


print("Sublists : ", sublists)
```

output :

```
Sublists :  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10], [11]]
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html