# How can I split a list into multiple sublists in decreasing size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example, if I had the list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

and wanted to make it into this:

```
[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],[10],[11]
```

How could I do this? FYI, the 11 at the end is a leftover, so any more variables would become something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],[10],[11,12,13,14,15]
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101942/split-a-list-into-sub-lists-of-decreasing-size

Comment: what if you have more element after 11? e.g 12, 13 and so what will be the expected output?

Comment: @L0987 No, because if you look carefully he does it like this:

[1,2,3,4] to [1,2,3,4],[2,3,4] etc when i want [1,2],[3],[4]

Comment: @AlwaysSunny The expected output is in the question, it's [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],[10],[11] and if there are more outputs it would be part of the last list

Comment: Could it be that you and [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72416699) have the same homework assignment?

Comment: As a hint, noting that 1+2 = 3, 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, you can use [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A000217) (comparing to the length of your list) to figure out how long the longest sublist should be. You can then create lists of decreasing length and will be left with a leftover amount. In general, though, you need to show your effort though and where you are stuck. Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that describes how to ask a good question.